# The party killed this important NPC right away: now what?

Tags: dnd-5e, published-adventures, npc, hoard-of-the-dragon-queen

My level 2 party of 5 killed

> Lennithon in the first encounter

in Greenest. What do I do?

I have thought about just running it normally but that won't work, because they each got 3,000xp making them level 4. This majorly upsets the balance of the game.

Also am I supposed to just scrap the later encounters?
I checked the rules so many times I lost count and I still couldn't find what I did wrong. I was thinking maybe since I have an artificer in my party and I havent really read up on it that much that I overlooked a class feature that they didn't really understand which resulted in some extra damage dealing.
It could have been the two guiding bolts critting making a total of 16 d6.
Also it could have been that I have three spellcasters that are all focused on damage dealing plus a barbarian and a rogue.

Comment: I'll be really interested to hear, if this is reopened, how 5 L2 adventurers took down an adult dragon that never gets within 25' of them and flies away once it's taken 24+ damage.

Comment: Welcome to the site 51131,  if you didn't already, Feel free  to take the [Tour]! And with the latest edits, this question will be very interesting.

Comment: To help make the question more precise, are you looking for more advice on how to rebalance the mecanical side of the game? Or how to rework a premade adventure once a major derailment like yours happened?

Comment: This needs way more background, because you obviously did something wrong. If you can pinpoint what it was, being honest and retconning might be an option, in order to consider that, more details about how that fight went down are needed.

Comment: Agreed.  If they killed the dragon at level 2, a pretty much impossible feat, then something is going wrong to where the usual advice about bumping up lesser enemies to account for the additional levels won’t be helpful - apparently levels and CR aren’t working they way they are supposed to in your game.

Comment: I feel like this should be closed until we can get more information. as @nitsua60 said, the creature should have left at 24-ish damage. and adult blue dragons have 225 hp. Even if every member crit hit their attacks and they were heavy hitting spells like chromatic orb, that's still a theoretical maximum of 240, if all 30 dice are max-roll. (just to prove a point of silliness)

Comment: @user51131 I know we're getting pretty tangential to your original question, but if you can give a play by play as best you can recall for how that fight went down, it might help us work out where it went wrong.